# Detect whether an acts_as_something line is present in a model or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Assuming the following module which allows to add acts_as_timeable functionality to an arbitrary model.

```
module Timeable
  module ActsAsTimeable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_timeable(options ={})
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Timeable::ActsAsTimeable
```

According to the last line, acts_as_timeable class method is made available in ActiveRecord::Base. So any model extending form ActiveRecord::Base will return true when calling `Model.respond_to?(:acts_as_timeable) => true`.

How can I detect whether a model actually acts_as_timeable based on whether a line starting with **acts_as_timeable**...

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_timeable
end
```

...(and maybe some options) has been added to the model or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the simplest way to do this is to set this state on the model class itself.

In `acts_as_timetable` you can set a class variable, and expose it through an accessor, like this:

```
  module ClassMethods
    def timeable?
      !!@timeable
    end

    def acts_as_timeable(options = {})
      @timeable = true

      # Rest of your code
    end
  end
```

Then you can check simply with `MyModel.timeable?`

Comment: Thanks, it's a working option... I have two questions here: 1.) I thought @name  indicates an instance variable and @@name indicates a class variable. If I am right, you defined an instance variable, but we need a class variable. I tried to prefix variable timeable with @@ and it causes a NameError when calling MyModel.timeable? Where is  the trick? 2.) What exactly does "!!" mean? Thanks again...

Comment: 1) You are right, this are instance variables, but they are *instance variables on the class*, because your module ActsAsTimeAble::ClassMethods is `extend`ed into the class. 2) !! forces the result to be either true or false. !(a falsy value) = true, ! that and you'll get false. Also look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/1699053

Comment: 1.) Ok, but wouldn't it be better to add it as a class variable on the class? Even if we choose to add it as an instance variable, in general, shouldn't we define instance variables inside module ActsAsTimeable but outside module ClassMethods? 2.) Ok, I think a better explanation is to turn the return value "nil", which is returned if acts_as_timeable is not present in MyModel and thus no instance variable "timeable" is declared, into a boolean value...

Comment: 1) Class variables are tricky with inheritance - I generally avoid them http://sporkmonger.com/2007/2/19/instance-variables-class-variables-and-inheritance-in-ruby When we define instance variable inside class methods, this instance variables become *instance variables on the class*. Classes are objects in ruby. That means that the class, let's say `MyModel` (which is an instance of a class), gains this instance variable and the method `timeable?`. This code is only run once per class. `timeable?` returns nil for classes that haven't set @timeable. 2) Sure, this is a matter of taste.